# Skipping task as it has no source files and no previous output files

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-task

This is my `build.gradle` which has three tasks (one for downloading the zip, one for unzipping it and other for executing the sh file). These tasks are dependent on each other. I am using Gradle 6. As these are dependent tasks I have used following command:

```
gradlew C
```

I get the error:

> Skipping task 'B' as it has no source files and no previous output files.

`build.gradle`:

```
task A {
    description = 'Rolls out new changes'
    doLast {
        def url = "https://${serverName}/xxx/try.zip"
        def copiedZip = 'build/newdeploy/try.zip'
        logger.lifecycle("Downloading $url...")
        file('build/newdeploy').mkdirs()
        ant.get(src: url, dest: copiedZip, verbose: true)
    }
}
          
task B (type: Copy, dependsOn: 'A') {
    doLast {
        def zipFile = file('build/newdeploy/try.zip') 
        def outputDir = file("build/newdeploy")
        from zipTree(zipFile)
        into outputDir
    }
}

task C (type: Exec, dependsOn: 'B') {
    doLast {
       workingDir 'build/newdeploy/try/bin'
       executable 'sh'
       args arguments, url
       ext.output = { return standardOutput.toString() }                        
    }
}
```

Comment: At the time your tasks `B` and `C` are executed, they are not configured, because `doLast` closures run **after** task execution. Since task `B` is not configured, it has no source files and gets skipped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried following and it worked. Rather than adding a separate task to copy, added the copy function in the task A itself

```
task A {
    description = 'Rolls out new changes'
    doLast {
        def url = "https://${serverName}/xxx/try.zip"
        def copiedZip = 'build/newdeploy/try.zip'
        logger.lifecycle("Downloading $url...")
        file('build/newdeploy').mkdirs()
        ant.get(src: url, dest: copiedZip, verbose: true)
        def outputDir = file("build/newdeploy")
        copy {
          from zipTree(zipFile)
          into outputDir
        }
    }
}

task C (type: Exec, dependsOn: 'A') {
    doLast {
       workingDir 'build/newdeploy/try/bin'
       executable 'sh'
       args arguments, url
       ext.output = { return standardOutput.toString() }                        
    }
}
```